# Two Buttons with equal width in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How can I get two buttons side by side in `ConstraintLayout` with fixed and equal length?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164956/1343788

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button 1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    />

<androidx.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
    />
 </androidx.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For androidx `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline`

Comment: @RiccardoBonesi thanks. Wasn't compiling before changing this tag.

Comment: Edited: Thanks @Riccardo... it in fact requires androidx schema