# Android constraint layout divide in horizontal

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I'm working with an Android project and I used `ConstraintLayout`.

I want to design the layout as two blocks which stay in horizontal line. Each block will get 50% of the width:

[image]

How can I do this with `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518746/5906447

Comment: use guideline inside constraint layout .

Comment: Why did you emphasise in the text that each block gets the same width but then show a picture where each block has a *different* width?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are Two ways you can do this.

- Using Chain Constraint
- Using Guideline Constraint

**1st** : Using Chain Constraint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2nd** : Using Guideline Constraint

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output** : Both gives same output.

[image: Output]